# Scroll the contents automatically after iframe finished loading

Tags: javascript, iframe

The requirement is I need load a external page in iframe dynamically, after finish loading, if the loaded page has v-scrollbar, need scroll the content automatically.

```
<iframe id="target" name="target" scrolling="yes" style="width: 100%;"></iframe>
document.getElementById('target').src = "http://www.yahoo.com";
document.getElementById('target').onload = function(){
        scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroller()',num);
}
```

In function pageScroller, I tried to set a timer:
    `parent.frames['target'].scrollBy(0,10)`,

it can't work. Then I tired the second way
`document.getElementById('target').scrollTop = document.getElementById('target').scrollTop+10;`

It can't work too. Seems this is because cross domain and browser's security consideration block it. 
Is there any other way I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think because of **same origin policy** you does not have permission to access inside Iframe.

This policy permits scripts to access content on pages that are originating **from the same site**.

Comment: I know it, is there any other way I can achieve requirement.